# dependency injection of Scheduler Quartz now works properly

Tags: c#, .net-core, quartz.net

I'm trying to use a Quartz SchedulerFactory, in this way:

i'm adding a scheduler factory as a singleton object in IServiceCollection like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
```

After this, i have a command handler, that i'm trying to inject this SchedulerFactory on the constructor of command handler:

```
    private readonly ISchedulerFactory _schedulerFactory;

    public TestCommandHandler(ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory)
    {
        _schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
    }
```

but when i try do start the application, the service providers throws this error for the command handler:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Quartz.ISchedulerFactory' while attempting to activate

Why does the service cannot find the implementation for ISchedulerFactory although i've added it to services as singleton?

Comment: Hi. Maybe ISchedulerFactory has some unregistered dependencies? Like you inject something into StdSchedulerFactory, but you haven't registered that in DI?

Comment: Add StdSchedulerFactory class to your question

Comment: @OlegI the StdSchedulerFactory is a built in class that came along with Quartz package, this class is a default implementation of ISchedulerFactory.

Comment: I've found a solution, i get the instance of scheduler factory by using `services.getService<IScheduleFactory>()` ant it works.

Comment: If you are able to get service from IServiceProvider, but it doesn't work when you inject it in ctor, there is something wrong. Do you register your TestCommandHandler in DI ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using application lifetime scope, alternatively, you can create an instance and register that as "singleton".

This rules out any non-managed dependency, such as registration of COM components, to cause such error.

```
var instance = new StdSchedulerFactory(/*whatever needed for initialization*/);
services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory>(instance);
```

Comment: So, you are able to do: `new StdSchedulerFactory(/*whatever needed for initialization*/);`?